# Need more mechanize documentation (python)

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm having a really hard time finding a good comprehensive source for Mechanize's documentation. Even the main documentation on [mechanize's site](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/doc.html) isn't really that great: it only seems to list examples.

Is there a more formal place for documentation where I can see lists of classes and methods for this module? I'm a bit new to python, so maybe there's a simple answer for this.

More specifically I need a good source of information for `mechanize.Browser()`, which I've only been able to find information on through random questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not happy with mechanize's site, then I'm afraid the best you can do is look at the examples you've found or at the code from the library ifself.

Regarding `mechanize.Browser` if you take a look at the code, then you'll see:

```
class Browser(UserAgentBase):
class UserAgentBase(_opener.OpenerDirector):
class OpenerDirector(urllib2.OpenerDirector):
```

So, for starters, you can assume that a `mechanize.Browser` object is just a specialized `urllib2.OpenerDirector`.

Answer (score 15):

UPDATED:
How about
https://github.com/python-mechanize/mechanize

*prior answer: A google search turned up the below, courtesy of one Joe.  He parsed the source through pydoc and posted the generated results.  Nice one, Joe.
http://joesourcecode.com/Documentation/mechanize0.2.5/
http://joesourcecode.com/Documentation/mechanize0.2.5/mechanize._mechanize.Browser-class.html*

Comment: Downvoters, it's not my fault links in a post from 4 years ago no longer work.