# Obtaining the label of the control of a form in Mechanize

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize

I am scrapping sites to analyse every form within to find a general pattern that will allow me to automate submitting search queries to these sites. So far, the names of many of the forms are either non-existent or unclear, and so I will need to scrap the associated label to gain meaning for the controls (fields).

The [Mechanize support site](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/forms.html) states that it is possible to extract a control from a form in a web page when searching for a specific label:

```
control = form.find_control(label="select a cheese")
```

I am looking for a solution to obtain the label from the control. The Documentation for Mechanize is poor [but the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288662/need-more-mechanize-documentation-python) provides a link to more detailed documentation, but I have been unable to find my answer there.

Has anyone managed to do this or found a workaround solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once had to do something similar when automating data submission to a form. I obtained a list of the names and labels of the controls as:

```
names = []    
labels = []     
for c in br.form.controls.__iter__():
    names.append(c.name)
    labels.append(c._label)
```

With these lists you can then select a form as:

```
control = form.find_control(name=names[0])
```

Comment: My issue is that some of the forms have no names, and so to interpret what the form is for I need to look at the label text for each individual control, I have all the controls already. I was looking at trying to pass the Mechanize form to BeautifulSoup and extracting the labels that way, although I'm having issues getting the Mechanize form back to HTML.

Comment: Ah,ok. I think this should give you a list of the label texts: `labels = [l.attrs['__text'] for l in form._labels]`